# How to change the Excel Online data programming

Tags: excel, rest, sharepoint, office365api

I want to be able to edit Excel file on Mobile device currently, we upload the excel file and display the file on Excel Online in WebView, but it seems that only iPad can edit it online, but not iPhone or Android phone.

I have tried to use SharePoint online, but I found that it only can edit data but cannot save data on server. Meanwhile it looks not pretty as Excel Online.

We just want to **use Excel online and find a way to modify data programmatically from the application code** like via [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) or [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) injection.

[image: example]